# GAE error uploading Quercus' resin.jar

Tags: php, google-app-engine, quercus

I'm writing a test app for GAE with PHP, the docs I read online said I had to download Resin 4.0 and extract the resin.jar and put it in my lib folder(http://wiki.caucho.com/Quercus_Google_App_Engine). Well, GAE wont let me upload it to their servers.

```
Unable to update app: Found a jar file too large to upload: "C:\projects\GAEtest\Temp\appcfg4969388681839327297.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\resin.jar".  Consider using --enable_jar_splitting.

See the deployment console for more details
Unable to update app: Found a jar file too large to upload: "C:\projects\GAEtest\Temp\appcfg4969388681839327297.tmp\WEB-INF\lib\resin.jar".  Consider using --enable_jar_splitting.
```

BTW, I'm very new to GAE and haven't found really good/straight forward tutorials on this... any info would be great!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the suggested `–enable_jar_splitting` option should fix the problem:

```
..\appengine-java-sdk\bin\appcfg.cmd –enable_jar_splitting update war
```

Have a look to [this](http://www.hm2k.com/posts/getting-started-with-quercus-in-google-app-engine) documentation on how getting started with Quercus in Google App Engine.

Comment: BTW, there are 2 dashes.. your post and the site have it wrong. 

For others who might see this... In Windows, I had to add quotes to the ..\appengine-java-sdk\bin\appcfg.cmd "--enable_jar_splitting" update war